Eyes Blink have problem
Good day,
My problem is when i make a shape key for eyes blink taking value 1, in between 0 to 1 there is a problem happens(pupil shows above lid) like my image. i used before a script that saw on youtube but this way doesn't work often.
Is there a way to fix this problem.
Thank you in advance
enter image description here


the problem of the shapekeys is that the movement between shape 1 and shape 2 will be linear for each vertex, so you can't make a sphere rotate for example, the interpolation will deform the shape. There are probably several solutions, depending on the shape of your eye and eyelid, for example you could use bones

@moonboots Thank you! i tried some solutions but one of them only have acceptable result which is i made shape keys several to close eye then created a driver and combine all in bone. the result is some how not perfect. BTW  i use sphere eyes.
